# Is there any use for the pg_type type?

Tags: python, postgresql, libpq

Is there any real world use for the *type* `pg_type`, i.e [type ids 71 and 210](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/27b77ecf9f4d5be211900eda54d8155ada50d696/src/include/catalog/pg_type.dat#L115). Although it's a bit of a faff, queries can result in this type output, as in the below  where an explicit cast to `pg_type` is used.

```sql
SELECT (
    1,'The "name",',1,1,1,TRUE,'a','a',TRUE,TRUE,'a',1,1,1,
    1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,'a','a',TRUE,1,1,1,1,
    (SELECT typdefaultbin FROM pg_type WHERE typname = 'time_stamp' LIMIT 1),
    1,'{{postgres=a}}'
)::pg_type
```

Context: I'm writing a Python PostgreSQL adapter, and want to know if it's worth writing/hooking up a parser for this type.

Comment: For every table in a Postgres database there is a corresponding entry in `pg_type`. As `pg_type` is a table it needs an entry for that.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Ah I didn't know that. But still, what's the implication of that for the _type_ `pg_type`?

Comment: Even tables have a type (because functions can return table(row)s) And the catalogs are tables too, so the need to have their types.

Comment: @wildplasser I might be starting to get it... and so a much simpler query returns values of type pg_type/71 for example: `SELECT pg_type FROM pg_type`. Thanks!